Next.js background image not showing using css
Any clue as to why my background image is not showing when i add a linear gradient. when i tak eout the linear gradien the background image shows up fine but when i add the linear gradient the background image doesnt show up.
 <div className="hero" style={{background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, black, white), url('/agent2.png')", backgroundSize: 'cover', backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>
        <div className="hero-container max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <Navigation />
        </div>
      </div>

this code works as it doesnt have the linear gradient but i want the linear gradient
<div className="hero" style={{backgroundImage: "url('/agent2.png')", backgroundSize: 'cover', backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>
        <div className="hero-container max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <Navigation />
        </div>
      </div>


When you set multiple background images, they stack top to bottom. Since your gradient is first in the list, it shows on top, covering your image. Flip the order so the image is on top instead, or make your gradient transparent.
The MDN docs for background-image show this in several examples, for reference.
